# How can i make this function in a functional programming way?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

How would I make this function into a pure function (functional programming)?

```
    fun validateOffer(offerValidateRequest: OfferValidateRequest, channelId: ChannelId, tenant: Tenant): OfferValidateRepresentation {

    val errorsList = mutableListOf<OfferValidateErrorsRepresentation>()
    val successList = mutableListOf<OfferValidateSuccessRepresentation>()

    offerValidateRequest.offers.forEach {
        val filterRequest = OfferGetRequest(it.id, it.type)
        val catalogs = findCatalogsWithOffers(filterRequest, channelId, tenant)
        val errorMessages = getOfferErrorMessages(it, catalogs, filterRequest)

        if (errorMessages.isEmpty()) {
            successList.add(OfferValidateSuccessRepresentation(it.id, it.type))
        } else {
            errorsList.add(OfferValidateErrorsRepresentation(it.id, it.type, errorMessages))
        }
    }
    return OfferValidateRepresentation(errorsList, successList)
}
```

I'm not very comfortable with these iterations in the lists of errors and successes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your function is already pure. It has no side effects.

But you still could avoid the mutable lists by using map, [partition](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) and a [pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html) destructuring declaration.

If I replace a for loop by functional operations, I try to use multiple maps, filters, flatMaps. The nice thing about this is, that between these operations the only shared data, is the collection you pass through.

```
val (successList, errorsList) = offerValidateRequest.offers.map {
    val filterRequest = OfferGetRequest(it.id, it.type)
    val catalogs = findCatalogsWithOffers(filterRequest, channelId, tenant)
    val errorMessages = getOfferErrorMessages(it, catalogs, filterRequest)
    Pair(it, errorMessages)
}.partition {
    it.second.isEmpty()
}

return OfferValidateRepresentation(
    errorsList.map { OfferValidateErrorsRepresentation(it.first.id, it.first.type, it.second.errorMessages) }, 
    successList.map { OfferValidateSuccessRepresentation(it.first.id, it.first.type) }
 )
```